# Unable to build flutter apk

Tags: flutter, build, apk, android-app-bundle

I am getting an error when trying to build appbundle for a Flutter app. I am very new to flutter and it is a project I bought online.

here is the error:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-14.4.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutternativeimage\FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\launch_review-3.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\iyaffle\launchreview\LaunchReviewPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
lib/ui/checkout/checkout3_view.dart:455:29: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
      currency: valueHolder.defaultFlutterWaveCurrency,
                            ^
lib/ui/common/ps_expansion_tile.dart:116:33: Error: Method 'readState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
        PageStorage.of(context).readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/common/ps_expansion_tile.dart:141:31: Error: Method 'writeState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
      PageStorage.of(context).writeState(context, _isExpanded);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/checkout/one_page_checkout/one_page_checkout_view.dart:791:31: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
        currency: valueHolder.defaultFlutterWaveCurrency,
                              ^
lib/ui/common/expansion_tile.dart:120:33: Error: Method 'readState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
        PageStorage.of(context).readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
lib/ui/common/expansion_tile.dart:147:29: Error: Method 'writeState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'PageStorageBucket' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_storage.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_storage.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    PageStorage.of(context).writeState(context, _isExpanded);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            103.1s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Flutter Projects\planhome> flutter --stacktrace
Could not find an option named "stacktrace".
```

Comment: Can you send GitHub link of code?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I am not on GitHub, is there anyway that I can share the code? and which code are you looking for?

Comment: No worries. I checked the question again. Which version of Flutter SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi, after running flutter --version, here is the report below:

Flutter 3.3.8 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 52b3dc25f6 (6 months ago) • 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
Engine • revision 857bd6b74c
Tools • Dart 2.18.4 • DevTools 2.15.0

Comment: Look at your `Dart Analysis` before you build the project. Don't you have there an error? Especially this error: `lib/ui/common/ps_expansion_tile.dart:116:33: Error: Method 'readState' cannot be called on 'PageStorageBucket?' because it is potentially null.`

Comment: Hi,I am now left with the below 2 errors below:
lib/ui/checkout/checkout3_view.dart:455:29: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
      currency: valueHolder.defaultFlutterWaveCurrency,
                            ^
lib/ui/checkout/one_page_checkout/one_page_checkout_view.dart:791:31: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
        currency: valueHolder.defaultFlutterWaveCurrency,